# Assign values to a column of one data frame based on values of another data frame with different number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have two data frames, `df_y` and `df_x`

```
df_y <- data.frame(int_area = c(0.00503201, 0.66491063, 1.40633472, 2.76595972, 
        3.38315429, 3.38842563, 4.43895167, 6.85371330, 10.17257506, 17.27029774), 
                  count=c(2,3,6,5,6,5,3,5,1,1))

df_x <- data.frame(int_area = c(0.00503201, 0.66491063, 1.40633472, 2.76595972, 
        3.38315429, 3.38842563, 4.43895167, 6.85371330, 10.17257506, 17.27029774)
```

I'd like to create column `df_x$count` based on both, `df_y$int_area` and `df_y$count`. Something like

```
if df_y$int_area = df_x$int_area then df_x$count = df_x$count.
```

I tried using `ifelse`:

```
df_x$count = ifelse(df_y$int_area == df_x$int_area, df_y$count, NA)
```

but I got the following error message:

> Warning message:
>   In int_area$int_area == y$int_area :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

then I tried using `%in%` but instead of == but I got this error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, count, value = c(2L, NA, 6L, 5L,  : 
>     replacement has 497 rows, data has 57599

Would appreciate very much any help on how to proceed.

Comment: This is a merge (or "left join") I think - does `merge(df_x, df_y, all.x=TRUE)` do what you want? Though it is probably dubious trying to merge on numbers with several decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df_x <- df_x %>% left_join(df_y, by = c('int_area' = 'int_area'))

> df_x
      int_area count
1   0.00503201     2
2   0.66491063     3
3   1.40633472     6
4   2.76595972     5
5   3.38315429     6
6   3.38842563     5
7   4.43895167     3
8   6.85371330     5
9  10.17257506     1
10 17.27029774     1
```